How to convert an ASP.NET Webforms user control to a DLL
I have an ASP.NET Webforms app where I'd like to add some HTML as a user control (Mycontrol.ascx) generated from another Webforms project. I've tried following the (rather old) articles Turning an ascx user control into a redistributable custom control and Embedded UserControls: Revisited but as they are both for Visual Studio 2005 (the first was updated for VS 2010), in 2022 the options don't seem to be the same. What I want to do is get the dll file (App_Web_MyTestUC.ascx.cdcab7d2.dll in the first article example) that I could reference in my main Webforms app and include the contained control, together with its code behind and the required libraries (jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.).
Indeed, I could just add it as a controller inside my main Webforms app, but I plan to use it also in other projects, keeping it as self-contained as possible. Any ideas are welcome, even if I can achieve the control to be distributable using a different approach.

We are testing it. It will take some time.

I recommend that you don't do this, for the reason that once a control is baked inside an assembly .dll it becomes effectively impossible to edit/tweak/improve/work-around. Instead, I suggest you keep it in source-form, but manage your projects differently to accomodate them better; for example, use git submodules or subtrees to pull-in your Controls/HTML/other-assets from a shared repo while still allowing them to be maintainable.

Thanks four your comment @Dai. I don't quite understand your point that "it becomes effectively impossible to edit/tweak/improve/work-around"; I could just edit the control, create the new .dll and use it in the other projects, couldn't I? On the other hand, I'm reading on Git submodules, and they might actually be a solution to what I'm looking for; thanks for the hint.

Ok a few things:
First up, that very old 2005 article still works 100% just fine when following the instructions to convert the user control to a server control and .dll.
So, while the instructions work just fine, and the result is a final single .dll? Well, one issue you noted should be avoided. You as a general rule NEVER want to include say Bootstrap, or jQuery or whatever as part of that control. Those are application wide JavaScript libraries that your application will require.
The reason of course is that near all your existing pages will have (and require) Bootstrap and jQuery and whatever other JavaScript libraries you are using. (say like jQuery.UI and jQuery.Toast for example).
If you include those script libraries in that server control (.dll), then each time you place that control on a page, you wind up loading Bootstrap, and jQuery 2 times. Worse yet, if you attempt to upgrade Bootstrap, or jQuery, then you not only loading those script libraries two times into the given web page, but you have to re-compile and re-update the server control references to new versions of Bootstrap, jQuery etc. This is simply not a maintainable setup. You or some other developer in a few months may well decide to update Bootstrap, or whatever, and then you find the page does not respect the new JavaScript libraries. And now which JavaScript libraries are being used in that page?
So, for JavaScript code that belongs to the user control, or the server control? Sure, no problem in such cases you are encouraged to add the JavaScript to that control.
However, general JavaScript libraries that are application wide should never be included in such controls. In other words, you simply adopt the design patten that if a user control or server control needs jQuery, or whatever? Then you "assume" that page must have those script libraries already available.
So worse than forcing the page to load such general JavaScript libraries two times, the difficulty in updating a page, or making sure that all markup code on a given page is using the same version of Bootstrap or jQuery or whatever becomes impossible to determine.
So, if you include general JavaScript libraries, then what version wil the page run?
The next issue?
While the steps outlined in that linked article to create and convert the user control into a server control and .dll works?
The elephant in the room left out of that article?
The approach outlined does not result in a server control that can be dragged + dropped from the toolbox. And it does not allow drag + drop from the project explorer view either.  And the result does not allow adding that control to the toolbox.
That means, you have to manually type in the markup for the control (and make sure markup syntax is 100% correct). You then also have to go to top of page, and add the assembly @Page directive manually by hand.
So, with a user control, you are free to drag + drop in the user control into any page, and not only is markup created for the control, but VS also generates and automatic places the correct @Page assembly directive for you at the top of the page.
For me, this is a deal breaker, since we all love user controls, and server controls, since they allow a simple drag + drop into the given page, and you are good to go.
Of course, a better approach to converting a user control to a server control (and .dll) is to create a new class project, and correctly setup and create a valid server control. In effect, there is no real automated conversion of a user control to a server control.
So, with a real user control, or server control?
The result is such controls can be added to the tool box, and used with a simple drag + drop from the toolbox into any given web page.
The major downside of building a server control is they don't have the nice .ascx markup page, and that means you have to write code behind to inject the markup.  This of course means significant extra work to convert a user control to a server control.
So, if you don't care about the drag + drop, and you don't care if you have to manually type in and add the page directive?
Then following the instructions in that article is in fact easier with vs2022.
So, create a blank new web site application project.
Let's create a user control with a simple text box, and button. When button is clicked, we will place text in the text box.
hence this:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test Button"
    OnClick="Button1_Click"
    />

And code behind is this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "This is server code";
    }

Then to convert into the .dll, following the article steps, we use the project publish, but ensure we select the option to build + create a .dll assembly for each and every page, and each and every .ascx page.
So, project->build->publish
And we have this:

And select these options in configure:

Now, publish to the folder.
We open up the bin folder under our publish to file folder, and we find the .dll for the user control:
Hence this:

So, even with vs2022, following those instructions works just fine (not sure what you mean that something is missing in vs2022 - those steps work just fine even 20 years later for vs2022).
As noted, now we can create a new web project or from an existing project, we add that .dll as a reference.
Now comes the hard part:
As I pointed out, converting a user control into a server control and .dll based on those instructions means that you can't use drag + drop, you have to manually type in the markup for the control, and worse yet, you also have to be hand type in the @Page assembly directive. That's the part left out of that article.
You gain a server control and .dll, with those instructions, but keep in mind the missing features I note above. In effect, the result is not really a practical server control that works how we expect most server controls to function.
However, the above instructions and that linked article does work when using vs2022, and you are 100% free to create a server control as per above instructions.

What's with the question mark characters?

Because the point about "if you don't care" is in fact a question, and I don't know if the poster cares - if they don't, then not a big deal - but they might! - so the context is that of a point being made that is a type of question.   I mean, do you really care that I used a "?" ?   -- (see how this works - I asking if you care about "?", and thus ended with a ?

I thought they were accidentally inserted by pasting from a text editor with a strange encoding. For example, this sentence seemed to be split in two by the question mark: "So, if you don't care about [...] then following the instructions in that article is in fact easier with vs2022.". No real worries, though.
